# SSRS not displaying page headers in browser, but fine in Exported reports

Tags: reporting-services

I'm developing a report using Visual Studio 2003, to be run and displayed in SSRS / Report Manager.

When the report is run, the page header does not display. However, if I export the report results to Excel, then the header is populated and displayed perfectly well.

The header displays fine in design view, but not in preview mode, or when run.

The header consists of a header JPEG image, and a few text boxes.

Answer (score 1):

This may seem bizarre, and un-related, but it's how the issue was fixed. Not because I did it this way to fix the above issue, but it's how the above issue resolved.

In my sproc that I was calling, to get the data, I changed the following code :-

```
CREATE 
    -- DROP
    PROCEDURE 
    -- exec 
      [dbo].Report_DOA_HP_REREPAIR

     @StartDate datetime ,
     @EndDate datetime
AS

IF @startDate IS NULL SELECT @startDate = GetDate()
IF @endDate IS NULL SELECT @endDate = GetDate()

SET @startDate = '2012-02-01'
SET @endDate = '2012-03-09'
```

to :-

```
CREATE 
    -- DROP
    PROCEDURE 
    -- exec 
      [dbo].Report_DOA_HP_REREPAIR

     @StartDate datetime ,
     @EndDate datetime
AS

IF @startDate IS NULL SELECT @startDate = Convert(datetime, '2012-01-01') --GetDate()
IF @endDate IS NULL SELECT @endDate = Convert(datetime, '2012-03-09') --GetDate()
```

Maybe it something was getting its knickers in a knot and re-compiling the sproc was the fix.

Bizarre but true. It's working fine now.